# Convert string to utf-16

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I have a text file with japanese characters. I read a line from it and want to convert it to utf-16 specifically. How can I do it using Python? My code looks like this -

```
with open("C:\\Users\\badri\\jap.txt", 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        u = line.decode(encoding='utf-16',errors='strict')
```

I get this error "LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-16"

The reason is I want it in utf-16 is because words are separated by spaces and so doesn't matter what language the text file is in.  I would be able to use space as a delimiter and count the number of words in the file.

Once separated, I can easily print them this way -

```
u1 = u'\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f'
u2 = u'\u0077\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064'
u3 = u'\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f\u4e16\u754c'
print u1
print u2
print u3

Hello
world
こんにちは世界
```

Comment: *because utf-16 words are separated by spaces*. I'm not sure what you mean there, but UTF-16 doesn't separate words out.

Comment: is this python 2.7 or python 3?

Comment: Sorry Martijn. It should have been "words are separated by spaces". The utf-16 in front is a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: I need to separate words from a text file that has words from many languages. For e.g If I have the following words in a text file "Hello world こんにちは世界", then I won't be able to separate out the words. Whereas if i converted it to utf-16, then I get u'\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f 
 \u0077\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064   
 \u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f\u4e16\u754c'. These are delimited by spaces and so I can count the different words in that line even if language is different. This is the only idea that I was able to come up with to separate words in a file that has multiple languages in it.

Comment: Cfreak - I am using Python 2.7. But no problems even if solution needs python 3.

Comment: I have now added an example towards the end of the question. Hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: `u'\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f \u0077\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064 \u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f\u4e16\u754c'` — this is not "UTF-16". It's just Unicode.

Comment: The file `jap.txt` has an encoding.  Maybe it's utf-16, maybe it's not.  You need to know what the encoding is, *decode* it, and then *encode* to utf-16.

Comment: @JoshLee I got it converted here  - https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter

Comment: @wim I created the file and I did not do anything special. Just copied english and japanese characters from the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends entirely on the encoding of the file.

Either way, you need to decode the line first, and then re-encode it so that it's utf-16.

```
with open(file_path, "r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        string = line.decode("utf-8").encode("utf-16")
```

Comment: I created that file and i just copied and pasted english and japanese characters into that file. Did not do anything else.

Comment: Also when I ran your code, I get the error "LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-16".  Is it related to my editor ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you created it, it still has some kind of encoding. And you need to figure out what that is before you can decode it. Look at [this](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) for example.